# Handling URL Rewrite in IIS5

Tags: url-rewriting, iis, http-code-500

On an older server, using IIS5, I have an error handling page which for some missing pages uses `Server.Transfer` to load other pages based on a database.

The pages all work for a browser but some systems e.g the W3validator gets an error when viewing the page (500 Internal Server Error). 
I have

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Status = "200 OK"
```

before the `Server.Transfer` but the error still seems to be there.
Very frustrating! Any suggestions as to why some systems fail when viewing the page would be welcome.

Comment: I think you need to phrase your question better - it's not clear what the problem is.